# Problem creating an API route to append a line in Google sheet

Tags: node.js, api, express, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to append lines via googleapis API in Node js, and the existant code is working for me but I tried to create an API to pass the values to append dynamically (from the frontend) but I couldn't do it and I get errors when I try to export the Oauth / callback in the autorize function.

Here is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];        
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';            
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {    
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);    
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.    
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), DoAppend);    
});    

/**    
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the    
 * given callback function.    
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.    
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.    
 */    
function authorize(credentials, callback) {    
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;    
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(    
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);            
  // Check if we have previously stored a token.    
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {    
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);    
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));    
    callback(oAuth2Client);    
  });    
}

/**    
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then    
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.    
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.    
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.    
 */    
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {    
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({    
    access_type: 'offline',    
    scope: SCOPES,    
  });    
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);    
  const rl = readline.createInterface({    
    input: process.stdin,    
    output: process.stdout,    
  });    
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {    
    rl.close();    
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {    
      if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);    
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);    
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions    
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {    
        if (err) return console.error(err);    
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);    
      });    
      callback(oAuth2Client);    
    });    
  });    
}

/**    
 * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:    
 * @see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Qezk7i2fUz24ldDR_pbPUptliLwzmu-t0fFyOgYm00/edit#gid=123987456    
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth The authenticated Google OAuth client.    
 */    
function DoAppend(auth) {    
  const sheets0 = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});    
  sheets0.spreadsheets.values.append({
    spreadsheetId: 'ID here',
    range: 'Testing',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    resource: {
      values: [
        [new Date().toISOString(), "Some value", "Another value"]
      ],
    },
    auth: auth
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
  })      
}
```

I just need to create an API to pass the values in parameters in the DoAppend function.

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
function DoAppend(auth = auth, body = null) {


  const sheets0 = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});

  sheets0.spreadsheets.values.append({
    spreadsheetId: ID,
    range: 'Testing',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    resource: {
      values: body
    },
    auth: auth
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
  })


}

module.exports = {DoAppend}
```

I tried to pass the values table with argument and use the function but I have an error :

```
TypeError: authClient.request is not a function
    at createAPIRequestAsync (C:\Users\user\Downloads\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src\apirequest.js:268:27)
    at Object.createAPIRequest (C:\Users\user\Downloads\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src\apirequest.js:43:9)
    at Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.append (C:\Users\user\Downloads\node_modules\googleapis\build\src\apis\sheets\v4.js:318:37)
    at Object.DoAppend (C:\Users\user\Downloads\controllers\synchronisation.js:138:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Downloads\index.js:10:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
```

Comment: Could you share the code corresponding to the values you want to append? Is your problem passing this values to `DoAppend`? You cannot just pass it as a function argument?

Comment: Yes but there is an "auth" argument in that function, how I'm going to pass it ? From the frontend for example ?

Comment: That depends on where your values come from. What's the problem with the `auth` argument? Can't you pass the data in a second argument? I think it would be useful to get the code where the values to append are declared, and in general, explain in more detail what is your desired workflow (when should the data be appended, etc.).

Comment: In the    values: [ [new Date().toISOString(), "Some value", "Another value"] , Iwant to pass that values as paramerters in an object for example.
 
I need an api route with POST method /api/append ! but there is that auth argument which I autorized to use that function, I can't delete it

Comment: @Iamblichus can you please see the EDIT

Comment: I still don't understand where the values are supposed to come from. Are they typed by the user, and coming from the frontend? Also, where is the code related to `authClient`? Where are you getting this error?

Comment: No I don't have an auth authClient , it's a google api error . Yes the values is an array of arrays typed by the user, and coming from the frontend ! 

for example I tried this in my index.js and I git that error : 

const Ctrl = require('./controllers/synchronisation')

var values =  [
  [new Date().toISOString(), "Some value", "Another value"]
]

Ctrl.DoAppend(values);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214157/discussion-between-iamblichus-and-xgeek95).

Comment: Hi @lamblichus can you please help me to chnage the code like you suggested

Comment: Global var MyAuth = null;


I changed the authorize function to authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => {
MyAuth = auth;
});

and function doAppend() {

const auth = MyAuth;

In the main I call : doAppend()

But I get code: 401,
errors: [
{
message: 'Login Required.',